# Uncaught ReferenceError: txtNoteRef is not defined - useRef - reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create simple react js app, below is my code snippet(Notes.tsx file)

```js
import React, { createRef, useRef } from 'react';
function NotesEditor(props: any) {
    const txtNoteRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    return (
        <div className={"row"}>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" ref={txtNoteRef} id="txtNote" className="form-control"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <input type="button" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save Note" onClick={handleSaveNote}></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    function handleSaveNote(event: any) {
        debugger
    }
}
export default NotesEditor;
```

can someone please explain why I am getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: txtNoteRef is not defined whenever I am trying to access it in method `handleSaveNote()` or how can I use `useref` properly? below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: `txtNoteRef` is defined inside `NotesEditor` but not inside `handleSaveNote`, where the error is thrown according to the stack trace. JavaScript has lexical scope. If you want the function to have access to that ref you have to declare the function inside `NotesEditor`, or pass it as argument to `handleSaveNote`.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-use-ref-diq76?file=/src/App.js

Comment: handleSaveNote is method inside NotesEditor and txtNoteRef is also defined at the same level where handleSaveNote is defined, i think there should be no issues accessing txtNoteRef from handleSaveNote, i think my code is not formatted properly in question

Comment: @RaviChaudhary yes i saw your codesandbox snippet, it is working fine but not working for me :(, btw i am using .tsx file could this be a reason ?

Comment: that should not be the reason. i updated my snippet with tsx extension and it works just fine. Can you create a codesandbox snippet with code thats closer to your actual code so that we can have a closer look. You might have missed something when porting code to showcase your issue here

Comment: coz on your code, `txtNoteRef` is not refered inside `handleSaveNote`

Comment: function handleSaveNote(event: any) {
        alert(txtNoteRef.current.value);
    } i am trying this and still getting error "Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to resolve this error by changing line `const txtNoteRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);` to `const txtNoteRef = useRef<any>();` and it worked!!!

```
import React, { createRef, useRef } from 'react';
function NotesEditor(props: any) {
const txtNoteRef = useRef<any>();
return (
    <div className={"row"}>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" ref={txtNoteRef} id="txtNote" className="form-control"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save Note" onClick={handleSaveNote}></input>
        </div>
    </div>
);
    function handleSaveNote(event: any) {
        debugger
    }
}
export default NotesEditor;
```